# Procurar carácter num array php

Tags: php

Imaginando que tenho o seguinte array:

```
$o_meu_array = array("123_rui", "125_joao", "287_manuel");
```

Agora quero encontrar dentro do meu array "123". Ao encontrar o 123, quero substituir o 123 por outro valor dado pelo utilizador. Por exemplo, se o utilizador meter "10", vai ficar "10_rui". É possível fazer isto?

Comment: quer o código ou o caminho das pedras ?

Comment: se possível o código senão todos os comentários são bem vindos. obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para substituir valores em um *array* você pode utilizar a função **[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)**

```
$meu_array = array("123_rui", "125_joao", "287_manuel");
$procurar = "/123/";
$substituir = "10";
$meu_array = preg_replace($procurar, $substituir, $meu_array);
```

**[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/7XNnhJ)**

Comment: Era mesmo isso. Agora só uma questão, é possível procurar pelo 123 e depois substituir o nome? por exemplo: 
procurar: 123
quando encontrar substitui o nome por joaquim
resultado: $meu_array = array("123_joaquim", "125_joao", "287_manuel");

Comment: @pc_oc Seria isso https://ideone.com/vGCmko ?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: caso fosse com números a expressão regular ficaria algo deste genero: $procurar = "/123_([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])*/";
certo? obrigado novamente

Comment: @pc_oc isso você faria `/123_([0-9])*/`, ou seja 123_qualquer_numero_qualquer_tamanho, você pode aceitar letras, números, caracteres e etc, para mais informações sobre expressões regulares veja este link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/os-php-regex1/

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez!